# Virtual environment development tool

Tags: virtual, environment, multiplayer, linden-scripting-language

I have to build a virtual environment for my "Virtual Reality" class like second life but not complicated as it is. I will use it to examine the effect of virtual environment in social life of handicaps and/or old people. So i need to build a collaborated virtual environment with general features like chatting, performing some tasks, playing little games etc. I need a high level tool because I do not have really much time for coding. Can you give me some development tool names? As I said the main goal is making questionnaire and evaluating not the designing the VE. If you know some free domains to build the environment it would be perfect too.

Comment: Do you know how much time it takes for someone with not so much experience to model things in 3D on a computer?

Comment: I'm sorry, but do you know what this sounds like? "I need to build a space shuttle. Not because I need the shuttle itself, but I need to ask the astronauts some questions about how it was being in that shuttle. Can someone show me some place I can quickly and easily build that shuttle, because I don't have a lot of time available for bulding it. Kthxbye." To build a virtual environment with anything remotely similar to any 3D world is a gigantuan task. You need a lot of time, and a lot of expertise in doing so. If you don't have much time to do it, you can't do it. Simple as that.

Comment: @thejh I didn't tell anything like I have no experience to model things I think you missed the question..

Comment: @lasse your example was so unmeaningful.. I said that I have no time for coding all the environment. I was asking for tools like OpenSimulator. If you dont have any answers just don't answer the question. You don't have to babble.

Comment: I'm sorry, but you really do need a lot of time to do this. If you don't understand that then it doesn't matter what I say, you'll just have to discover that yourself.

Comment: And to be honest, if I don't have any answers, but I have comments, I'll still leave a comment. I can't answer your question because you don't want the answer: It can't be done. So I leave a comment. You're of course free to ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

If the main goal is not building the VE, why don't you use Second Life as a tool? Designing content and running the experiment is considerable task on it's own.

Comment: What do you mean expensive? If you don't need to own land, account itself is free.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot see anything else than [Opensimulator](http://opensimulator.org) to fit your needs.

If you need to host your own server world, just download the Diva Distro [here](https://github.com/diva/d2/downloads). (diva-r13981.zip)

Learning to run and use OpenSimulator is sometime not that easy, but it's pleasant to do if you like technical stuff.

If you do not feel confortable enough to host your own world server, you might prefer to benefit from alternative grid hosters like [OSGrid](http://www.osgrid.org/), [ReactionGrid](http://reactiongrid.com/), [InWorldz](http://inworldz.com/), [NewWorldGrid](http://www.newworldgrid.com/lang/en-us/)... . All of those Grid providers offers reliable and cheap alternatives to Second Life, all of them are based on Opensimulator.

I would recommend kindly to use the [Imprudence Viewer](http://wiki.kokuaviewer.org/wiki/Imprudence%3aDownloads) instead of the official Second Life viewer, because it allows to switch easily from one grid to an other.

Do not hesitate to open accounts, log in-world and ask around you.